# How to simulate the Internet in Cisco Packer Tracer?

Tags: cisco, internet

I have a network designed in the image given below which is configured with RIPv2. I need to connect this network to the internet in simulation. How to simulate internet in cisco packet tracer? Thanks.

[image: network digram]

Comment: I hope for you that you don't need to use GRID on those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously in packet tracer I have setup an additional router simulating google dns as the IP address (8.8.8.8) to act as the internet based location. This has helped as a simple simulation allowing test ACL's and routing.